# compass not importing extension in some files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, compass-sass

This looks a bit odd to me.

I'm using Rails 3.2.3 with compass-rails 1.8.6 on Cedar stack.

Extensions are working fine in Heroku when importing them in the .sass files main "application" folder.

I have created a second stylesheet folder in `/app/assets/stylesheets/mobile` and a `/app/assets/stylesheets/mobile.scss` file.

In dev mode everything works fine but on Heroku it doesn't recognize the extensions for files inside this folder. It is looking weird because it seems to be working fine for the application folder files.

```
2012-05-02T01:42:36+00:00 app[web.1]: Load path: /app
2012-05-02T01:42:36+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (File to import not found or unreadable: compass/css3/box-shadow.
2012-05-02T01:42:36+00:00 app[web.1]:   (in /app/app/assets/stylesheets/mobile/header.css.sass)):

#app/assets/stylesheets/mobile/header.css.sass
@import "compass/css3/box-shadow"

# Gemfile
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'compass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only `application.css` is precompiled by default. Other top level files will need to be explicitly added in `config/environments/production.rb`

e.g.

```
config.assets.precompile += ["mobile.css"]
```